# Visual studio code Linux - Squiggle lines don't show up on .h files, but work well on .cpp files

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I noticed that somehow VS Code C/C++ Intellisense is not working on .h files. But they work pretty well on .cpp files.
I tried all the header files are not showing any errors, and it starts to be really furstrating, because it doesn't show if I mistype something.
I have installed the C/C++ extension by Microsoft.
Why is this happening?

I checked the settings but didn't find any good solutions there.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3503

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] including the `c_cpp_properties.json` file, header file demonstrating "missing" intellisense, and .cpp file demonstrating working intellisense?